# Подсветка при наведении мыши

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Делаю портфолио, возникла совсем не очень гениальная идея. Меню.

[image]

Как сделать так, чтобы оно подсвечивалась как на картинке: при наведении мыши светились слова (home, potfolio...), наподобие:

[image]

Есть идеи?

Извините за вторую картинку. Просто не знал, как еще это можно было бы показать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждый пункт меню рисуешь двумя картинками (с подсветкой текста и без). По умолчанию выводишь без подсветки, при наведении мыши меняешь на картинку с подсветкой.

А вообще-то так делать нехорошо. Лучше оставь фон для меню, а пункты меню выводи текстом. Тогда можно баловаться со стилями самого текста, например [text-shadow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-shadow)

Comment: Это же портфолио, цель - показать, что умеет только картинками :-)

Answer (score 2):

С text-shadow не всегда получится требуемый эффект (если рассчитывать на кроссбраузерность). Очень уж различны вариации исполнения его в IE, Chrome, Opera, FF и прочих. Лучше-таки именно графическое исполнение разных состояний (разные картинки для hover, active) - по крайней мере можно быть абсолютно уверенным в том, что разные версии браузеров отобразят ваш сайт так, как надо.